# Does SQLite3 not support foreign key constraints?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am have a problem with SQLITE3.

I have created 2 tables `persons` and `orders` using the following SQL script:

```
sqlite> create table Persons(
            P_Id int primary key,
            LastName varchar,
            FirstName varchar,
            Address varchar,
            City varchar
        );

sqlite> create table Orders(
            O_Id int NOT NULL,
            OrderNo int NOT NULL,
            P_Id int, 
            PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
            FOREIGN KEY (P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
        );

sqlite> insert into Orders values(1,77895,3);

sqlite> select * from Orders;

1|77895|3

sqlite>
```

Even though the persons table is empty rows can be inserted into the `orders` table.

It does not show any error.

How is this possible.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In SQLite 3.x, you have to make the following query **every time** you connect to an SQLite database:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Otherwise SQLite will ignore all foreign key constraints.

Why every time? Backwards compatibility with SQLite 2.x, according to the the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).

In SQLite 4.x, FK constraints will be [enabled by default](https://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/design.wiki).

Comment: Every time? It is not possible to have it permanently enabled?

Comment: @mafu Yes, every time. I've edited the answer to explain why.

Comment: Just ran into this today. This is the dumbest effing thing.

Answer (score 2):

[SQLite Foreign Key Support](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

This will enable foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the documentation? The [main page](http://sqlite.org/docs.html) says it's introduced with version 3.6.19. The [link](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) shows how to use foreign keys (Your code is correct).

Does your code give any error messages you omitted? Did you check all preconditions in specified in the documentation?

Comment: then please tell me how to remove my older version and install new version of sqlite3.

Comment: @AbbasMulani how to uninstall and install depends on your os and other things. Check which version is currently installed and how it was installed. The the step to install a new version is not so big.

Comment: see documentation here   at https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html "Tip: If the command "PRAGMA foreign_keys" returns no data instead of a single row containing "0" or "1", then the version of SQLite you are using does not support foreign keys (either because it is older than 3.6.19 or because it was compiled with SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined)."

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you have foreign key constraints enabled in your SQLite: http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable

Comment: it does not showing anything when i enter command
PRAGMA foreign_key;

Answer (score 0):

One important note that other answers do not mention is that the commands to enable/disable foreign constraints checks like:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

have no effect within a started transaction. Here's the quote from the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys):

> This pragma is a no-op within a transaction; foreign key constraint
> enforcement may only be enabled or disabled when there is no pending
> BEGIN or SAVEPOINT.

The command should be run before transaction is started. I faced this issue when I tried to disable a FK constraint check temporarily to address a performance issue but this may still cause a problem if the command is used at inappropriate time.