# Flask-SqlAlchemy Sqlite Foreign Key constraint not working?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my models:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('item_type.id'))
    purchase_price = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    purchase_transaction_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('purchase_transaction.id'))
    supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('supplier.id'))

class ItemType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_type = db.Column(db.String(ITEM_TYPE_LENGTH), index=True, unique=True)
    items = db.relationship('Item', backref='item_type', lazy='dynamic')
```

So this is what I did:

```
>>> db.session.add(models.Item(item_type_id=170, purchase_price=111, purchase_transaction_id=1, supplier_id=1)) 
>>> db.session.commit()
```

I added a new Item `item_type_id` is 170, but the table of item_type only has `id` until 20. And if I check my database, the `item` is successfuly added, and if I do a query like `ItemType.query.get(item.item_type_id)`, `None` will be returned - which means the foreign key does not exist

I have read the docs in [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/core/constraints.html) and [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html), they both should have foreign key constraint, I wonder why it is not working in mine

Comment: `query.get` does not do what you think it does. You should be doing `query.filter_by(item_type_id=170).scalar()` instead.

Comment: You also need to show the code that you are using to turn foreign keys on in sqlite.

Comment: What do you mean a code showing to turn into foreign keys? I'm using Flask-sql alchemy `item_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('item_type.id'))`, so I'm assuming `db.ForeignKey()` does it for me?. Oh sorry about the `query.get`, I edited my post

Comment: [You need to turn on foreign keys manually.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support) sqlite by default has them off.

Comment: ah!! no idea I need to activate it first, thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does SQLite3 not support foreign key constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937713/does-sqlite3-not-support-foreign-key-constraints)