# SQLite won't throw error when inserting non-existing foreign key value

Tags: sqlite

I have a litte problem with my SQLite database, especially with the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  key INTEGER NOT NULL,
  what TEXT NOT NULL,
  else TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (key) REFERENCES foo (key) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

If I understand the SQLite documentation the right way, attempting to insert a row into `bar` that does not correspond to any row in the `foo` table should fail and thow an error or something.

Unfortunately the following command works, even if no key 42 existis in `foo`:

```
INSERT INTO bar (key, what, else) VALUES (42, "something", "else");
```

This will create a row in `bar` with the given values (key = 42), while there exists no row in `foo` with the key 42.

Is it me or what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you set the pragma `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON`

Answer (score 2):

As posted by @kijin on [Does SQLite3 not support foreign key constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937713/does-sqlite3-not-support-foreign-key-constraints)

> In SQLite 3.x, you have to make the following query every time you connect to an SQLite database:
>
> ```
> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
> ```
>
> Otherwise SQLite will ignore all foreign key constraints.
>
> Why every time? Backwards compatibility with SQLite 2.x, according to the documentation.
>
> In SQLite 4.x, FK constraints will be enabled by default.