# Pandas to_sql ignores foreign key constrains when appending to sqlite table?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, foreign-keys

I use the pandas method `to_sql` to append a DataFrame to some sqlite table. The sqlite table has a  foreign key constraints on a column `id_region` that pandas should consider. The available values for `id_region` are 1, 2.

If the DataFrame contains a non-existing `id_region` value 3, I would expect `to_sql` to throw an exception.

However, the data is written to the database without exception and the foreign key constraint is ignored.

If I manually change the value in the sqlite database using Navicat, for example to 1 and then back to 3, I get the expected error.

=> The foreign key constraint in sqlite seems to work but not when inserting the data.

=> How can I tell pandas to consider the foreign key constraint?

Example code to reproduce the issue:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'demo.sqlite'

id_region = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': 1, 'label': 'foo'},
    {'id': 2, 'label': 'baa'},
])
id_region.set_index(['id'], inplace=True)

data = pd.DataFrame([
    {'id': 1, 'id_region': 3, 'value': 1}
])
data.set_index(['id'], inplace=True)

create_data_table_query = 'CREATE TABLE `data` (' +\
               'id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ' +\
               'id_region integer NOT Null, ' +\
               'value real NOT NULL, ' + \
               'FOREIGN KEY (id_region) REFERENCES id_region(id)' + \
               ')'

with sqlite3.connect(file_path) as connection:
    id_region.to_sql('id_region', connection, index_label='id')

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(create_data_table_query )
    data.to_sql('data', connection, index_label='id', if_exists='append')
```

Tables created by the above code:

**id_region**:

[image]

**data**, referencing id_region:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] PS When crossing software layers, check what actually got across & what it does in its layer.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraints must explicitly be enabled for each connection in sqlite3 and pandas does not seem to have an option to do so automatically. The command 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON' has to be executed for the connection before it is passed to the `to_sql` command of pandas:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()    
cursor.execute(create_data_table_query )
cursor.execute('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON')
data.to_sql('data', connection, index_label='id', if_exists='append')
```

sqlite4 will have this enabled by default.

Also see

[Does SQLite3 not support foreign key constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937713/does-sqlite3-not-support-foreign-key-constraints)